# How do I reinstall Adobe Design and Web Premium CS6 on my Mac?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I tried to open Photoshop I got a message that files were missing.  Someone (mis?)informed me that I had to uninstall Photoshop and then hit the button to reinstall. Instead the whole file along with Acrobat Pro and a whole bunch of other stuff disappeared. And there was no reinstall button. Is there a simple way to fix this?  I have the license key for the suite.  Do I need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Just download the installation files of the CS6 trial version from Adobe again:

https://helpx.adobe.com/en/x-productkb/policy-pricing/cs6-product-downloads.html

Once you've installed the trial, you can upgrade it to the full version using your license key.

Comment: Do I have to uninstall the other parts of CS6?